# How can I test my iPad app on my actual iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am developing my first iPad app using the iOS SDK 4 and Xcode 3.2.  I have written a simple Hello World and have been able to run it in the iPhone simulator.  I would like to figure out:

1. How can I get an iPad simulator?
2. Is it possible to test my app on my actual iPad without signing up for a developers license for $99?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: This has been asked and answered plenty of times. You can't run apps without an ADC membership. It's the price of entry.

Comment: I thought the 'price of entry' would be the iMac that we had to run out and buy just to satisfy the simple client request of "Can you put a shortcut to this video file on the iPad's menu so we can click to open it directly?"

Comment: And here I was thinking that the awesome HTML5 support would negate the need for local apps ^^

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617992/personal-iphone-application-without-paying

Comment: Just bill your client for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK includes an iPad simulator.  I don't have my Mac in front of me, but you should be able to choose which device to target when you launch the simulator.  You can also switch between iPhone and iPad mode from within the simulator - check the Hardware menu.

Yes, you have to have a paid developer membership to deploy code to your device.  That's the only official way.

Comment: I was able to find the iPad simulator option, I had to first upgrade my Target for iPad and then I could select it.

Answer (score 7):

There are unoffical ways to get your app onto your device, you have to jailbreak it and install software called AppSync from cydia. This voids your warranty if Apple find out (restoring the device to it's original settings using the restore button in itunes means they can't tell, so jus trestore before you go to an Apple shop) and if they do find out it might prejudice them against you as a developer (but chances are very slim)
(I have no problem giving specific details as the US Government  has said that jailbreaking is legal)
http://www.pcworld.com/article/201892/us_government_iphone_jailbreaking_is_fair_use.html

Comment: I wish we could, however I do not think our clients would be happy about us voiding their warranties for their equipment.

Comment: @Mike C: You won't void their warranties if they buy the app through the app store.

Comment: Testing an app using this unofficial way is fine as long as you clean up after yourself. If your clients are an enterprise or something like that I think Apple allow you them to put non App store apps on their iDevices that are specific to their company/etc. (ie they don't want all their confidential info on the app store)

Answer (score 1):

If you have jailbroken, then install app sync from the Hackulo.us repo. Just sync your app in iTunes without signing it. It will work easy as Pi!

Answer (score -1):

This is yet another way to keep flash from getting to iPads, if you could put your own on the device without going through apple then you could also put someone else's. I think it should be allowed, but if something doesn't work on software that isn't officially released it shouldn't be supported by Apple.