# How to test the iPad app in iPad hardware (not in simulator)

Tags: xcode, ipad

After I'm done with build and test on iPad simulator, I need to test the app on iPad hardware.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you've paid for a developer key, you should be able to open the Organizer window, set up your device, and then select the device rather than the simulator as the target in XCode. See [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/00-About_the_iOS_Application_Development_Workflow/introduction.html) for details.

If you haven't and won't buy a developer key, you'll have to jailbreak your device. In that case, the answers to [How can I test my iPad app on my actual iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338482/how-can-i-test-my-ipad-app-on-my-actual-ipad/3338622#3338622) may help you.