# Is there any "Hello world" tutorial featuring XCode 4 for building app for jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode4, jailbreak

Recently I hoped to build the most simplest iPhone app using XCode 4 and put it onto jailbroken device. Unfortunately, for a programmer who never used XCode, this task turned out classic *the mission impossible*.

The vast majority of examples use xcode 3.x, not 4.x, which have considerable differences, and I'm not yet knowledgeable enough to find equivalent steps in xcode 4.

Examples of such discussions:

> > [How can I deploy an iPhone Application from Xcode to real iPhone device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device)
> >
> > [iPhone App Minus App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store)

Could anyone point me to some relevant tutorial or discussion?
Would be grateful,

Thanks,

Comment: do you want to just make an app and put it onto a jailbroken device because you don't have a license or do you want to have a .deb app and do you want to use things that you can only use on jailbroken devices?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I just want to try iPhone development, but I don't have license (yet). Not particularly interested in using things only available in jailbroken devices :)

Comment: if you have a jailbroken device you just need to install an app from cydia and setup xcode a little bit ;) but i think i can't post that here ;) you know....does stackoverflow has PM? (private message)

Comment: Jailbreaking an iPhone is perfectly legal, specially if you don't accept Apple's EULA.

Comment: _just need to install an app from cydia and setup xcode a little bit_ Yeah, I suspect that :) What I'm looking for, is particular instructions for xcode4..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

install the app called "**AppSync**" from cydia ;)..google will help you out ;)
and than do the following with xcode4:

Here: [How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device)

Do the following part: **Enable Xcode's to Build on Jailbroken Device**

Comment: Sure, did all that. Unfortunately, that example does not tell how to add 'New Run Script Build Phase' in XCode4. When I go to 'Editor->Add Build Phase', all sub-items are grayed out there. Could you suggest a workaround?

Comment: that's not neccesary...just make all till point 4. and than start building. I also did the same and it works still with the newest sdk and xcode4 ;)

Comment: Great! Ok, after I run Product->Archive, I get .xcarchive file. How can I deploy it to iPhone? When I click "share (ipa)", XCode gives me "Identity: no valid provisioning profiles found". And refuses to create .ipa

Comment: did you set in your project settings: "Don't code Sign" and did you install the correct AppSync? And did you edit the plists of xcode to deactivate the signing? Try Product -> run edit: is your iphone connected? and did you go to the organizer and press "Use for Development" for your device?

Comment: Yeah, seems like it's working now (running on device straight from XCode). Thanks! However, even though the app is running on device, XCode gives me this "Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 1035."

Comment: that's because you didn't join the iphone developer program and the error says you that you can't use live debugging (the console) -> you won't see any NSLogs or something....could you accept my answer? It helped you right?

Answer (score 0):

See [How can I test my iPad app on my actual iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338482/how-can-i-test-my-ipad-app-on-my-actual-ipad/3338622#3338622) on how to install the application on jailbroken hardware. Here is a [hello world in XCode 4](http://www.e-string.com/content/quick-intro-xcode-4), I guess you'll find more floating around in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my blog : You need to follow the following steps in order :

1. Allow ur apps to be debugged and tested on ur Jailbroken device -- 
   http://techtalktone.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/testing-your-ios-apps-on-a-jailbroken-device-2/
2. Create your first XCode App to be tested on the device --
   http://techtalktone.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/hello-world/

Hope this helps :D 
Sasha

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for other readers is an automated app available called JailCoder: http://www.jailcoder.tk – It automates this whole process and enables you to restore to original settings.