# Run app on iTouch w/o iTunes

Tags: iphone

I have written a small app using Ojective-C w/ XCode. It's only for personal fun and I don't want to pay Apple $99 to just let it run on my iTouch. Is there any alternative for me to run it on iTouch instead of iPhone simulator? Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Personal iPhone application without paying ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617992/personal-iphone-application-without-paying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install an app on a stock OS iOS device except from the App store, or through a paid iOS Developer certificate (individual, company or enterprise).  There are no alternatives for app installation.

As for paying the $99 yourself... if you have a friend who is already registered as a Company in the iOS Developer Program, and isn't planning on using all of their allowed 100 UDID's, perhaps you could bum a "team membership" off of them, have them add you as a team member (consulting contract or whatever), and use their Company Developer enrollment to create a team member's Developer certificate, instead of paying the $99 yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Not legally, as you need to register the device, obtain a signing certificate, etc. which is only possible if you're a registered developer.

Comment: jailbreaking is not illegal. http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2010/07/feds-ok-iphone-jailbreaking/. I would not jailbreak my devices, and it might damage your device if done not properly. You also might loose any warranty on the device. The advantages of registering for an account are early access to (beta) firmwares, an apple developer forum and you can run your applications on up to 100 devices without putting it in the store.

Comment: @Bastian - Totally, I meant "legal" in terms of what's permitted under Apple's terms and conditions/EULA. No law is being broken in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you jailbreak, you can use a fake certificate and install it through SSH.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make it an ipa, you can register as a free developer and get the sdk I think, and the $99/year is just for firmware betas, if that's wrong then I think you can also just drag the folder.app into iTunes and sync

Comment: no.. without an paid developer account you can't install applications on a non jailbreaked device. not directly and not using itunes